# Matplotlib: how to display a line with different colors base on the line data

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a numpy array which takes only two values `0.0018` and `0.0018001`

```
price_high_y = [0.0018 0.0018 0.0018 0.0018001 0.0018001 0.0018 0.0018 0.0018]
```

What I would like to do is to display this line with the values 0.0018 in black and 0.0018001 in yellow. It should be an horizontal line. I am a bit stuck.. any idea? thanks!

Comment: What do you mean when you say "to display this line with the values"? Do you mean annotations? You just have two unique points to plot. Your plot will have several lines running back and forth between these two points. What you mean by "display" is highly unclear right now. Please include some hand drawn sketch if possible in your answer OR add more explanation

Comment: Basically it will be a horizontal line where all the values `0.0018` are in black and the `0.0018001` are in yellow. I do not know how to explain it more clearer...

Comment: What do you want to have on the x-axis?

Comment: The two values are so close that they will be hard to distinguish on a linear scale. Work around is to just plot two horizontal lines at y = 0 and y = 1 let's say and then just label the y-ticklabels with your two values. Are you fine with that?

Comment: ok and how do you change the colors of these two values?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want

```
price_high_y = np.array([0.0018, 0.0018, 0.0018, 0.0018001, 0.0018001, 0.0018, 0.0018, 0.0018])

yvals = sorted(np.unique(price_high_y))
colors = {0.0018: 'k', 0.0018001: 'y'}

for i, y in enumerate(yvals):
    plt.axhline(i+0.5, color=colors[y])

plt.yticks(np.arange(len(yvals))+0.5, yvals) 
plt.xticks([0, 1])
plt.show()
```

[image]